# Updating multiple columns using apply function on a single column. The apply function returns two lists

Tags: python, data-science, nltk, stanford-nlp

I have a function returning two lists while applying it on a column. I want to map each list on a separate column, while calling the function only once, as I have millions of input rows:

I have tried below code however not getting the desired output:

```
def NERTag_ent(a):
    n=nl.ner(a)
    pr=[x[0] for x in n if x[1]=='PERSON']
    org=[y[0] for y in n if y[0]=='ORGANIZATION']
    return(tuple((pr,org))

df['Per'],df['Org']=df['n1'].apply(NERTag_ent)
```

> df['Per'] column should contain all the person and df['Org'] should contain all organisation.

Answer (score 1):

This should achieve what you want:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

def process(val):
    return (val + 1, val + 2)

df[['d', 'e']] = df['c'].apply(process)
```

Comment: The answer I am getting while using the suggested code is different from what I wanted to achieve:  df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

def process(val):
    vl1=[val,val+1]
    vl2=[val,val*3]
    return (vl1, vl2)

df[['d', 'e']] = df['c'].apply(process) . This gives an output:  a b c d e
0 0 1 2 [2, 3] [3, 4]
1 1 2 3 [2, 6] [3, 9]